# How to convert time as 00:00:00 for specific value using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

I have a  dataset with one input and date ,time.
I just want to convert time into 00:00:00 for specific value which is contain in input column, and other time will be display as it is.

I tried a code and it gave me 00:00:00 for specific value , but other time show as NaT.

Can anyone help me to solve the error?

my code:

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                    format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = df['x3'].eq(5)
df['Duration'] = np.where(df['x3']== 5, df['time_diff'], np.datetime64('NaT') )
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```

Then it gave me this output:

```html
date   time        x3 duration
10/3/2018 6:15:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 6:45:00   5 00:00:00 
10/3/2018 7:45:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:00:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:25:00         0       NaN
10/3/2018 9:30:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 11:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 13:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5 00:00:00
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 15:25:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 16:25:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 19:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 19:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 22:05:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5 00:00:00
10/3/2018 23:40:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5 00:00:00
10/4/2018 13:00:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0 NaN
```

But what I expected output is :

```html
date   time        x3 duration         expected output is
10/3/2018 6:15:00         0 NaN                    6:15:00
10/3/2018 6:45:00   5 00:00:00               00:00:00
10/3/2018 7:45:00         0 NaN                    7:45:00
10/3/2018 9:00:00         0 NaN                    9:00:00
10/3/2018 9:25:00         0       NaN                    9:25:00
10/3/2018 9:30:00         0 NaN                    9:30:00
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0 NaN                    11:00:00
10/3/2018 11:30:00 0 NaN                    11:30:00
10/3/2018 13:30:00 0 NaN                    13:30:00
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5 00:00:00               00:00:00
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0 NaN                    15:00:00
10/3/2018 15:25:00 0 NaN                    15:25:00
10/3/2018 16:25:00 0 NaN                    16:25:00
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0 NaN                    18:00:00
10/3/2018 19:00:00 0 NaN                    19:00:00
10/3/2018 19:30:00 0 NaN                    19:30:00
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0 NaN                    20:00:00
10/3/2018 22:05:00 0 NaN                    22:05:00
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5 00:00:00               00:00:00
10/3/2018 23:40:00 0 NaN                    23:40:00
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5 00:00:00               00:00:00
10/4/2018 13:00:00 0 NaN                   13:00:00
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0 NaN                   16:00:00
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0 NaN                   17:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with create new column by condition - with `0 timedelta` and with column `time` converted to timedeltas:

```
df['Duration'] = np.where(df['x3'].eq(5), np.timedelta64(0), pd.to_timedelta(df['time']))
print (df)
         date      time  x3 Duration
0   10/3/2018   6:15:00   0 06:15:00
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5 00:00:00
2   10/3/2018   7:45:00   0 07:45:00
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   0 09:00:00
4   10/3/2018   9:25:00   0 09:25:00
5   10/3/2018   9:30:00   0 09:30:00
6   10/3/2018  11:00:00   0 11:00:00
7   10/3/2018  11:30:00   0 11:30:00
8   10/3/2018  13:30:00   0 13:30:00
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5 00:00:00
10  10/3/2018  15:00:00   0 15:00:00
11  10/3/2018  15:25:00   0 15:25:00
12  10/3/2018  16:25:00   0 16:25:00
13  10/3/2018  18:00:00   0 18:00:00
14  10/3/2018  19:00:00   0 19:00:00
15  10/3/2018  19:30:00   0 19:30:00
16  10/3/2018  20:00:00   0 20:00:00
17  10/3/2018  22:05:00   0 22:05:00
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5 00:00:00
19  10/3/2018  23:40:00   0 23:40:00
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5 00:00:00
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   0 13:00:00
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   0 16:00:00
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   0 17:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. This is what I am looking forward.